# displaying mulitiple field of checkbox with php

Tags: php, html

i have a form with different checkbox fields. However, I was able to display their values using a foreach loop but was wondering if it possible to display them via how they are selected. below is my code.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="states.php" method="post">
    Draft<input type="checkbox" name="states[]" id="design_states" value="Draft">
    Design<input type="checkbox" name="states[]" id="design_states" value="design">
    Review<input type="checkbox" name="states[]" id="design_states" value="Review">
    Approved<input type="checkbox" name="states[]" id="design_states" value="Approved">
    Issued For Construction<input type="checkbox" name="states[]" id="color" value="Issued For Construction">                      
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<body>
</html>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['states'])) {
      $name = $_POST['states'];

      echo "You chose the following workflow: <br>";
      foreach ($name as $states){
        echo $states."<br />";
      }} // end brace for if(isset

    else {

      echo "You did not choose a workflow.";

    }
?>
```

if a user picks issued for construction first followed by draft I want that values to be displayed as picked not draft first and then issued for construction.

Comment: can you be more detail about your question?

Comment: I don't understand - you want the order that someone checked the boxes?

Comment: Specifically your final sentence doesn't make any sense: "if a user picks issued for construction first followed by draft I want that values to be displayed as picked not draft first and then issued for construction."

Comment: @eatpeanutbutter yes I want the order of how the checkbox where picked

Comment: @gabrieltong thanks I will try it out

Comment: You'll probably have to build your array with Javascript. There's no way in HTML/PHP to record the chronological order boxes are checked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "You chose the following workflow: <br>";
foreach (array_intersect($states, $name) as $state){
    echo $state."<br />";
}

echo "You don't chose the following workflow: <br>";
foreach (array_diff($states, $name) as $state){
    echo $state."<br />";
}
```